# c#: Inherited class get property, "return this.x as DerivedClass" or "return base.x as DerivedClass". What's the difference?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am looking through some code and I saw that a derived class has a get property:

```
{ get { return base.hwSystem as DerivedHardwareSystem; } }
```

where `DerivedHardwareSystem : HardwareSystem` and `hwSystem` is a member of `HardwareSystem`.

What is the difference between the following?

```
{ get { return base.hwSystem as DerivedHardwareSystem; } }
```

and

```
{ get { return this.hwSystem as DerivedHardwareSystem; } }
```

Thanks!

Comment: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) & [base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If `hwSystem` is overriden, `this.hwSystem` will use that override, whereas `base.hwSystem` will ignore the override and use the `hwSystem` defined in the base class. If `hwSystem` is not overriden, there is no difference between them.

Comment: So, if `hwSystem` is a field of `HardwareSystem` then it cannot be overridden and both options will yield the same result? Which of the two would be considered "best practice" or more acceptable?

Comment: @Jon I don't believe either of the two would be considered best practice or more acceptable. That would be down to whatever you wish your coding practices to be. I personally don't use either unless it's required and would only use `base.` if I wanted to bypass the local definition. If there is no local definition, the choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

[Base Class & Derived Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) Here is an explanation of what the .Base key word mean I will also put a link to MSDN that will explain even further

The base keyword is used to access members of the base class from within a derived class

The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method.

Answer (score 0):

If your subclass has an overridden or new implementation of `hwSystem`, then `this.hwSystem` references the version in the subclass, and `base.hwSystem` references the version in the base class.

If the subclass doesn't override or create a new version of `hwSystem`, which is what you describe, then `base.hwSystem` and `this.hwSystem` refer to the same implementation. Keep in mind that if someone adds a new implementation in the future, then you're in the situation described above.

Answer (score 0):

They would generally be the same, unless the derived class is overriding the `hwSystem` property already present in `base`. In that case, `this.hwSystem` could be a completely different thing.